# What is the meaning of the bold part here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Content](http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/Undertheinfluence/going-going-gurgaon/)

> Was Gurgaon’s ‘Millennium City’ tag that successful? Did the words ‘Millennium City’ make your follicles **turn all** futuristic and make you want to take your Millennium Falcon out for a warp drive with your incredibly tall and hairy **eye-candy Wookie spouse in the next seat (with the driver driving in front)?**

What is the reason of capital 'w'?Is it a metaphor?

I don't understand what he is referring to.

Comment: A [Wookiee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookiee) (note the extra 'e') is a species from Star Wars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did the words ‘Millennium City’ make your follicles **turn all** futuristic

The phrase "Millennium City" has a very sci-fi, futuristic feeling to it. Here, *turn* means "become". "All" can mean "completely" or "extrememly". So the author is asking

> Did the words ‘Millennium City’ make your follicles **become completely** futuristic.

I think he is trying to ask "Did those words make you that excited?" Something like that.

> [Wookiees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookiee) (/ˈwʊkiːz/) are a fictional species of intelligent, hirsute bipeds from the planet Kashyyyk in the Star Wars universe. They first appeared in the 1977 film Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope. The most notable Wookiee is Chewbacca, a companion of Han Solo.

This is an image of Chewbacca.
[image]

Species names are often capitalized.
*Example.*

> The species [Tyrannosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus) rex (rex meaning "king" in Latin), is one of the most well-represented of the large theropods.

Yes, it is a metaphor (not because of the capitalization). Presumably, his wife is not a Wookiee. Calling her a Wookiee is insulting since I doubt any woman wants to look like a Wookiee.
This, and the Millennium Falcon are references to [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars). It seems the city has been referred to the "Millennium City", but I don't know if "Millennium City" is also a reference to Star Wars.